# Please help with this specific fatal error upon trying to run a third party .jar file

Tags: jdk, openjdk, jar

I would like to run the open source program Zettelkasten; it would be great for my work and I hope very much you can help me to get it running!! Thanks in advance!!!

The program is this:

http://zettelkasten.danielluedecke.de/
https://github.com/sjPlot/Zettelkasten/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04LTS on 64 bit.

I'm one of those who changed from Windows XP, so please assume I really have no clue at all.
I installed Java some time ago by copy-paste frome some Ubuntu website somewhere and now I have openJDK 8 and 9 (9, yes, don't know how to get rid of it).

I downloaded Zettelkasten.zip from the website, unpacked it to home, where I have .jar now.

This is what happens:

> db@db-W65-W67RZ:~$ java -jar Zettelkasten.jar
>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3dc60f6009, pid=5284, tid=5322
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build
>   9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src) Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit
>   Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode,
>   tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64) Problematic frame: C 
>   [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
>
> Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be
>   processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or
>   dumping to /home/db/core.5284)
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   /home/db/hs_err_pid5284.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.
>
> Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben) db@db-W65-W67RZ:~$

This is the log-file:
(Sorry - I wanted to hide it or find some other way with markdown, but the only way I saw in the formatting tips would have been to hide it line by line?? Google only found a gitlab issue on how to do a vertical scroll bar, but I'm sure it exists, so my apologies!!!)

- OK, it seems I can't make a post that long. So for posting the log file, what can I do, please?? Any way to attach it I do not see?

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8bb78e5009, pid=4162, tid=4200

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
Problematic frame:
C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19

Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/db/core.4162)

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: Zettelkasten.jar

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, 8 cores, 15G, Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Time: Mon Apr 20 07:42:14 2020 CEST elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f8bb0430800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=4200, stack(0x00007f8b02817000,0x00007f8b02918000)]

Stack: [0x00007f8b02817000,0x00007f8b02918000],  sp=0x00007f8b02913100,  free space=1008k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
C  [libfontmanager.so+0x33f8e]
C  [libfreetype.so.6+0x14d2b]  FT_Stream_Seek+0x1b

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.initNativeScaler(Lsun/font/Font2D;IIZI)J+0 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.<init>(Lsun/font/Font2D;IZI)V+26 java.desktop@9-internal
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 java.base@9-internal
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+85 java.base@9-internal
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5 java.base@9-internal
j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+65 java.base@9-internal
j  sun.font.FontScaler.getScaler(Lsun/font/Font2D;IZI)Lsun/font/FontScaler;+39 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.TrueTypeFont.getScaler()Lsun/font/FontScaler;+21 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FileFontStrike.<init>(Lsun/font/FileFont;Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)V+204 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FileFont.createStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+18 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.Font2D.getStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;Z)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+92 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.Font2D.getStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+3 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(I)Lsun/font/PhysicalStrike;+23 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics()Lsun/font/StrikeMetrics;+31 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics()V+28 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;)V+62 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;)Lsun/font/FontDesignMetrics;+128 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Font;)Ljava/awt/FontMetrics;+15 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(Ljava/awt/Font;)Ljava/awt/FontMetrics;+2 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.getPreferredSize(Ljavax/swing/plaf/synth/SynthContext;Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/swing/Icon;IIIIII)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+110 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLabelUI.getPreferredSize(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+82 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+26 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+1 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$NodeDimensionsHandler.getNodeDimensions(Ljava/lang/Object;IIZLjava/awt/Rectangle;)Ljava/awt/Rectangle;+222 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.tree.AbstractLayoutCache.getNodeDimensions(Ljava/lang/Object;IIZLjava/awt/Rectangle;)Ljava/awt/Rectangle;+20 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.updatePreferredSize(I)V+24 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.rebuild(Z)V+65 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.setModel(Ljavax/swing/tree/TreeModel;)V+7 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.setModel(Ljavax/swing/tree/TreeModel;)V+75 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.propertyChange(Ljava/beans/PropertyChangeEvent;)V+193 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire([Ljava/beans/PropertyChangeListener;Ljava/beans/PropertyChangeEvent;)V+27 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Ljava/beans/PropertyChangeEvent;)V+71 java.desktop@9-internal
J 1321 C1  java.desktop@9-internal9-internal (59 bytes) @ 0x00007f8b9a45e8cc [0x00007f8b9a45e020+0x00000000000008ac]
j  javax.swing.JTree.setModel(Ljavax/swing/tree/TreeModel;)V+188 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JTree.<init>(Ljavax/swing/tree/TreeModel;)V+117 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JTree.<init>()V+4 java.desktop@9-internal
j  de.danielluedecke.zettelkasten.ZettelkastenView.initComponents()V+269
j  de.danielluedecke.zettelkasten.ZettelkastenView.<init>(Lorg/jdesktop/application/SingleFrameApplication;Lde/danielluedecke/zettelkasten/database/Settings;Lde/danielluedecke/zettelkasten/database/AcceleratorKeys;Lde/danielluedecke/zettelkasten/database/AutoKorrektur;Lde/danielluedecke/zettelkasten/database/Synonyms;Lde/danielluedecke/zettelkasten/database/StenoData;Lde/danielluedecke/zettelkasten/database/TasksData;)V+574
j  de.danielluedecke.zettelkasten.ZettelkastenApp.startup()V+398
j  org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run()V+24
j  java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+21 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+32 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1 java.desktop@9-internal
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 java.base@9-internal
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+18 java.base@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V+183 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9 java.desktop@9-internal
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000010002 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f8b02913100 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8bb0430800
RBP=0x00007f8b02913110 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8bb0430800
RSI=0x0000000000010002 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000000001db is an unknown value
R11=0x00007f8bb78e4ff0: JNU_GetEnv+0x0000000000000000 in /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/libjava.so at 0x00007f8bb78c8000
R12=0x00007f8aec309320 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f8aec342870 is an unknown value


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000010002
RSP=0x00007f8b02913100, RBP=0x00007f8b02913110, RSI=0x0000000000010002, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x00000000000001db, R11=0x00007f8bb78e4ff0
R12=0x00007f8aec309320, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00007f8aec342870
RIP=0x00007f8bb78e5009, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f8b02913100)
0x00007f8b02913100:   0000000000000000 55f587bf670ca500
0x00007f8b02913110ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

... [had to delete to shorten post]

VM Arguments:
java_command: Zettelkasten.jar
java_class_path (initial): Zettelkasten.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/home/db/bin:/home/db/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/db/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/db/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/db/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/db/.rvm/bin:/home/db/.rvm/bin:/home/db/.rvm/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xc12c20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xc12c20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0xc12c20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=00000000000010000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0xa3b600], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0xc12c20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0xa3b4a0], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0xa3b870], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0xa3b870], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0xa3b870], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0xa3b870], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
uname:Linux 4.4.0-177-generic #207-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 16 01:16:10 UTC 2020 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.23 NPTL 2.23 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 63408, NOFILE 1048576, AS infinity
load average:0,57 0,57 0,55

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       16318540 kB
MemFree:        11497736 kB
MemAvailable:   12574804 kB
Buffers:          153900 kB
Cached:          1570424 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          3282640 kB
Inactive:        1239012 kB
Active(anon):    2801228 kB
Inactive(anon):   427156 kB
Active(file):     481412 kB
Inactive(file):   811856 kB
Unevictable:          32 kB
Mlocked:              32 kB
SwapTotal:      16662524 kB
SwapFree:       16662524 kB
Dirty:              2312 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2798080 kB
Mapped:           712104 kB
Shmem:            430536 kB
Slab:             136108 kB
SReclaimable:      81704 kB
SUnreclaim:        54404 kB
KernelStack:       17120 kB
PageTables:        52472 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24821792 kB
Committed_AS:    8501404 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      159084 kB
DirectMap2M:     3921920 kB
DirectMap1G:    12582912 kB


CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 94 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

CPU Model and flags from /proc/cpuinfo:
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single intel_pt ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp kaiser tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d

Memory: 4k page, physical 16318540k(11497736k free), swap 16662524k(16662524k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src) for linux-amd64 JRE (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src), built on Apr 14 2016 20:05:37 by "buildd" with gcc 5.3.1 20160413
```

END

@Norbert:

```
db@db-W65-W67RZ:~$ java -version  
openjdk version "9-internal"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)  
db@db-W65-W67RZ:~$ update-java-alternatives -l  
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  
java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64       1091       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64  
db@db-W65-W67RZ:~$ dpkg -l | grep jdk  
ii  openjdk-8-jre:amd64                           8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04                                 amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT  
ii    openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64                    8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04                                   amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)  
ii    openjdk-9-jre:amd64                             9~b114-0ubuntu1                                          amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-9-jre-headless:amd64                    9~b114-0ubuntu1                                          amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)  
db@db-W65-W67RZ:~$ dpkg -l | grep jdk  
ii  openjdk-8-jre:amd64                           8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04                                 amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64                  8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04                                 amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)  
ii  openjdk-9-jre:amd64                           9~b114-0ubuntu1                                          amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-9-jre-headless:amd64                  9~b114-0ubuntu1                                          amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
db@db-W65-W67RZ:~$ which java  
/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: Please add output of `java -version`, `update-java-alternatives -l`, `dpkg -l | grep jdk` and `which java` to the question body. Also note that I can launch this application on 16.04 LTS using openjdk-8-jre.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the answer and for editing the formatting.

In the error message it says in the beginning it is using version 9 indeed.

But using the graphical interface I tried "open with" and chose version 8, and nothing happened either.

I don't know how to force a start with openjdk 8 in the terminal to show you what happens. 

openjdk-9 seems to be the default.

If you can tell me how to get rid of openjdk-9 without messing up everything, that would be great too :D

Comment: You can follow my answer below.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it works as expected with `openjdk-8-jre`.

So I would recommend to install the same Java version, select it and use the application:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre

sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

java -jar Zettelkasten.jar
```

Also please note that [Zettlr](https://www.zettlr.com/) [supports Zettelkasten method](https://www.zettlr.com/post/what-is-a-zettelkasten).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
It kept saying 'no alternative' / 'alternative does not exist', nothing new seemed to happen, but - I think Zettelkasten loves the different openjdk version you set :D
It seems a newbie can't give you a positive vote as thanks. I'm sorry.

Comment: Had a look at Zettl.
Neat!! 
Maybe it was meant I run into problems and come here to ask?
Thank you very much!